# Boost::Python Windows 7 64 Bit

Tags: python, boost, windows-7, 64-bit

I can't seem to build boost::python correctly on my Windows 7 64Bit machine.  It's vanilla 32bit python 2.6.4 in the c:\Python26 directory.

Pastebin is here of the debug build output :  http://pastebin.com/m7d70f13e

Cheers,

Al

Comment: I don't have an answer, but if you're willing to help resolving this, join the #boost channel on freenode, and ping 'volodya' there. If you are not used to IRC, you can install Firefox extension called Chatzilla -- it has freenode amoung the preconfigured networks, so you just have to start it, click on network and join the channel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On IRC, we have found the following procedure fixes the problem:

1. Open tools/build/v2/tools/python.jam
2. There, locate the following code:

   ```
   if [ version.check-jam-version 3 1 17 ] || ( [ os.name ] != NT )
   {
       # Prior to version 3.1.17 Boost Jam's SHELL command did not support
       # quoted commands correctly on Windows. This means that on that
       # platform we do not support using a Python command interpreter
       # executable whose path contains a space character.
       python-cmd = \"$(python-cmd)\" ;
   }
   ```
3. Remove that code block completely.

I'll create an issue in Boost issue tracker and investigate this.

Comment: Has this made it upstream yet? I just got this error in boost 1.51 and see that https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5023 is still open. Do you need help in investigating?

Comment: Yeah, this happens too in 1.53. @Vladimir, what's the status for this bug??